How often do you need to re-create the connection to SQL Server?
I did an experiment with the speed of writing to the database. I have several tables where logs are stored. I took 1 million logs and sent them in batches of 750 records into the database, while measuring the speed of processing requests by the SQL Server. These 750 records are just plain 750 INSERT INTO's.
In the graph below you can see the distribution of processing time for each batch. Look at these 4 columns. I think they arose due to the re-creation of the connection to the SQL Server.
My questions are:

Am I right?

If yes, I'm curious how often do I need to recreate the connection if I want to handle it myself? Are there any rules/guidelines/researches about it? I would be grateful for any relevant information and links.


My goal is to achieve as less average processing time as possible.

P.S. For working with database I'm using EntityFramework Core with single DbContext created:
var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
dbContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
while(queueIsNotEmpty)
{
    var batch = GetBatch(size:750);
    dbContext.AddRange(batch);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Version of SQL Server is 2019, EF Core 6.0.1

Very interesting. But you're wrong. First of all, see SQL Server Connection Pooling.

After each dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(), call dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear(), it will speedup EF Core. After 10 execution in ChangeTracker will be 7500 records which needs to be processed for detecting changes. Removeing them fro ChangeTracker will save memory and CPU.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I forgot to mention that change tracker is disabled. Updated the question. Thanks for the comment

If you want outright insert performance then consider using bulk load methods, such as SqlBulkCopy or EFCore.BulkExtensions these will upload many rows at once.

These 750 records are just plain 750 INSERT INTO's. - Nope. EF can use Batching. Also see Inserting multiple rows - MERGE can be used.

"I forgot to mention that change tracker is disabled" - it is not disabled it is used extensively SaveChanges do not work without change tracker.

Specify the exact version of EF and Sql Server.

@Charlieface I looked at this library and SqlBulkCopy, but I'm afraid they are not suitable for me, since I read somewhere that this function gives performance only for large insert volumes. In my case, 1 million is pre-filled for the experiment, but in production it will look like a constant stream of individual records.

@AlexanderPetrov Version of SqlServer is 2019, EF Core 6.0.1

Might be worth batching them up and inserting them when they get to a certain level (or also after a certain amount of time).

@Charlieface yes, that's exactly what happens in this code - they are batching in 750 records. Time condition is also there, I omitted it for simplicity

Could be checkpoint, but my guess is that it's garbage collection.

So why wouldn't bulk insert methods work? 750 is enough to make it worthwhile.

I haven't still got the data, but some years ago I benchmarked SqlBulkCopy against EF, using 1.000 inserts at a time. SqlBulkCopy was approximately 500 times faster than EF. Ok EF has improved, but I would still expect SqlBulkCopy to win hands down. Other techniques of batch insertion (json,xml,SqlDbType.Structured) were about half the speed of SqlBulkCopy, but still way faster than single inserts. Interestingly there was little difference between issuing single inserts between SqlConnection / SqlCommand and EF.
